# How can I test the shape of data passed into an Apollo GraphQL query in React Testing Library?

Tags: jestjs, graphql, apollo, react-testing-library

I am following the official doc here: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/development-testing/testing/ to create tests for my react component.

However, I can't seem to find a way to test the shape of the data that is passed into the mutation and I am interested in doing so as that ensures that my code will work as expected.

To elaborate. let's say this is what some pseudo code looks like:

```
const [doMutation] = useMutation(MUTATION)
...
await doMutation({...data})
```

In my test (jest/react-testing-library), I would like to:

```
expect(doMutation).toHaveBeenCalledWith({...data});
```

Comment: mutations are called with variables object, shape must match with defined ... variables ( https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#variables ) ... with props required or not, depends on mutation/input type specs

Comment: What's the error?

Answer (score 0):

You can use generated Typescript types that will help. You'll know your GraphQL schema changes when Typescript will begin to yell.

We've done this with the `apollo codegen:generate` command:
https://www.leighhalliday.com/generating-types-apollo

This helped our frontend team know when the backend schema changed and what needed to be fixed. It was awesome!